# How to add a desktop project written in C++ into a web project written in C#

Tags: c#, c++, image-segmentation, edge-detection

I want to use an open source project features in my web project. I've been developing my project by using C# in Visual Studio. Is there anyway to use this project codes like adding them as a library? I'm not good at in programming field and I'm quite new.

Someone adviced me to add this EDISON (Edge Detection and Image Segmentation) project (developed as a desktop application by using C++) into my web project as an .exe application. But I couldn't find a way to add the input parameters that program needs.

Is the only way to use this project in my web project is rewriting the codes by using C#? I do not even know the algorithm anyway :(

Thank you for any help!

Link for the EDISON Project: http://coewww.rutgers.edu/riul/research/code/EDISON/doc/overview.html